# How to find another Safari workaround related to alt text, and the Box Model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Because of some well deserved downvotes, this question has been given a serious overhaul. (lesson learned :))*

Scenario: I work on a CMS, where Users can add `style` like width and height or `alt` to an `img` tag. We usually put the `img` tag in a `picture` tag that lives in a `figure` but even that is not a guarantee. We optimize for these images by storing them in an array of possible sizes. So the `src` is not known until we have made calculations on the `img` to figure out what image to load in that `src` attribute.

```
<picture>
  <img src='' alt='a long alt text' class='imageWithAlt'>
</picture>
```

In Safari a `console.log` of the width is about 92.

The Problem: On our end that 92 could either be the alt text or `'style=width: 92px'` that the User decided to apply.

The Hack: To get a better idea for the width, we would take out the `alt`

```
$element.attr('alt', '').css({ margin: 0, padding: 0 });
```

Then a `$element.width();` would give the width without alt text. If that amount was less than our magic `40px`, then we would look to fill the parent container instead. At least we used to use this Hack until I don't know when Safari now just makes it's Box Model around the `alt` and doesn't care if it later is removed or not. So now this example would skip our check of the parent container and render a smaller version of image than the User intended.

Question: Is there another work around in Safari that anyone can think of?

Example HTML:

```
<figure>
  <picture>
    <img src='' alt='a long alt text' class='imageWithAlt'>
  </picture>
  <picture>
    <img src='' alt=''  class='imageWithNoAlt'>
  </picture>
</figure>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
let imgWithAlt = $('img')[0],
    imgWithNoAlt = $('img')[1];

console.log('imgWithAlt width: ', imgWithAlt.width);
console.log('imgWithNoAlt width: ', imgWithNoAlt.width);

// previous solution to get width or height without alt text
imgWithAlt.removeAttribute('alt');

console.log('imgWithAlt width after removing alt: ', 
imgWithAlt.width);
```

Example CSS:

```
img {
  background: #eee;
}

figure {
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
}
```

And here is a [link to the jsfiddle, if you use in Safari, you'll see the difference and in Chrome we have a way to keep out the 16X16 icon that currently displays so our Hack will work in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/timproctor/zf0vhcj6/107)

Comment: "true height" after the image has loaded? Taking in account css, `html` width attribute, or literally the [dimensions of the source](https://caniuse.com/#search=naturalWidth) file? You need to define your question more

Comment: I need a way to distinguish between height and width values that are a result of `style` properties set by the User, and the height and width that gets set as a result of there being `alt` text. So when I say "true height", I mean to say the height and width when alt text are not part of the calculation.

Comment: I [wrote up an example but in Safari](https://imgur.com/a/KHOvFVB), the css height/width look as desired and I don't see the alt text at all

Comment: Please provide a clearer example, better still an [MCVE]. The alt attribute is normally only displayed in graphical browsers when the image is unavailable and therefore would normally not play any part in width or height calculations.

Comment: @JonP great points and because of your suggestions, I went ahead and edited the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Alt contains W x H as text in

```
<img src="img/hero.jpg" id="image" alt="">
<script>
var img, width, height;
img = document.getElementById("image");
width  = img.width;
height = img.height;
img.alt = width + ' x ' + height;
</script>
```